# Debug a ruby Gem? Openshift Origin

Tags: ruby, debugging, rubygems, openshift

I am curious of something.

I am using an opensource system called Openshift Origin.

It's produced by redhat. It is fairly large and the code is found here: https://github.com/openshift/origin-server

The thing I want to do is debug it. I'm trying to print values by inserting "puts @" in the code, but nothing is being displayed and when I attempted to write to a tmp file I had the same problem! 
I am just trying to display what values the member variables are actually getting from the config files. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

By default, Rails (what OpenShift uses to serve web requests) will not write puts to where you expect.  Use Rails.logger.debug("...") which will write to /var/log/openshift/broker/production.log